# MySQL full join issue for a view

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do some sort of full join on two tables to create a View but can't figure out the correct mysql query. Joining two tables by overloading some values.

Let's take these three tables:

**Company table**

```
ID  Name
---------
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

**Tools table**

```
ID  Tool        Version
------------------------
1   Hammer      1
2   Saw         1
3   Screwdriver 1
4   Wrench      2
```

**CompanySpecialTools table**

```
ID  ToolID  CompanyID   Tool
-------------------------------------------
1   2       1           Frame Saw
2   3       1           Phillips screwdriver
3   3       1           Slot screwdriver
```

Basically, the CompanySpecialTools table "overloads" some of the Tools for a given Company.

The view I'm trying to create should produce the following result for the following queries:

```
Select * from myview where companyID=1 OR companyID is null

ToolID  CompanyID   Tool
--------------------------
1       NULL        Hammer
2       1           Frame Saw
3       1           Phillips screwdriver
3       1           Slot screwdriver
4       NULL        Wrench



Select * from myview where companyID=2 or companyID is null

ToolID  CompanyID   Tool
--------------------------
1       NULL        Hammer
2       NULL        Saw
3       NULL        Screwdriver
4       NULL        Wrench
```

Comment: You might wonder why I need a view for this...
The database is used in an iOS app that doesn't have any direct access to the database but uses a JSON API that can only query ONE table or ONE view at a time, with filters such as WHERE, GROUP and ORDER.

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error it seems I found a solution.

The following query answers my question:

```
SELECT t.ID as ToolID,
s.CompanyID as CompanyID,
COALESCE(s.Tool, t.Tool) as Tool
FROM Tools t
LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanySpecialTools s ON s.ToolID = t.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT ID as ToolID,
null as CompanyID,
Tool
FROM Tools
```

Adding a GROUP BY produces the desired result.

```
SELECT * FROM myview where companyID=1 OR companyID is null GROUP BY ToolID
```